# Badge on NavigationBar Button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need Your help again.I create one view controller in this view controller both navigation bar button have badge with number.I have tried and search every where but I am not getting any solution of this problem and every where they are just provide the solution for tabbar or on custom button.

so now I have need badge on navigation bar button,help me out of this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: ur idea of having a badge on Navigation bar is quite diff... But think twice on it coz Navigation bar will change every time u navigate between diff views (that is not the case with tabbar).

Comment: @hpiOSCoder but What can I do there is no TabBar so I need on that navigation bar only and its ok if we navigate to other view any how that will I manage.

Comment: Okkk got it.. Then I think proposed solution by 'iOS Developer" is promising. Accept it. It would really helps others. BTW good que proposed. +1upvote for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom view containing a button and badge and add that view to the right or left bar button of navigation controller. Thats the only way you can do it, else there is no native way to add badge and button in navigation bar button item.

**Edit:**

Do Some thing like this,

```
 UIView *BtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,35)];
        UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,35)];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [BtnView addSubview:myButton];
        [myButton release];

        UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:BtnView];
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
        [BtnView release];
        [barButton release];
```

Comment: OK I will try button what is bagde its image or view?

Comment: first thing tell me how I will add view On Dynamic Navigation bar button

Comment: Do Accept the answer if it helps, so that others can take help from it. :)